Is it possible to approximately compile Toffoli using H and CSWAP?
Question:
Given all controlled-SWAP (CSWAP) and Hadamard (H) gates on 3 qubits, is it possible to approximately compile the Toffoli (CCX) gate?
Discussion
From basic simulations, it appears that all $\text{CSWAP}$s and $H$s on 3 qubits generate an infinite group. This is a necessary condition for this question to be true since $\text{CCX}$s and $H$s on 3 qubits are known to generate an infinite group.
By approximate compile, I mean that for any $\epsilon$ a product of $\text{CSWAP}$s and $H$s exist (call it $U_{\epsilon}$) such that $\|U_{\epsilon}-\text{CCX}\| < \epsilon$.
I'm interested only in the 3-qubit case without the use of ancillas or encoded (approximate) universality.

TL;DR: Nope. The triple tensor product of the $+1$ eigenstate of the Hadamard gate is a $+1$ eigenstate of every product of the controlled-SWAP gate and the Hadamard. This is not the case for Toffoli, so Toffoli cannot be approximated as such a product arbitrarily well.
Let $\langle A,B\rangle$ denote the set of unitaries we can obtain by taking all possible finite products of $A$ and $B$ and let $\overline{S}$ denote the closure of $S$ in the topology induced by $\|\,.\|$, i.e. the set of all unitaries that can be approximated arbitrarily well by the unitaries in $S$.
First note that $\text{CCX}\in\overline{\langle \text{CSWAP},H\rangle}$ if and only if $\text{CCZ}\in\overline{\langle \text{CSWAP},H\rangle}$. We will disprove the second statement. Let $|h\rangle:=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ denote the $+1$ eigenstate of $H$ and let
\begin{equation}
|hhh\rangle:=|h\rangle\otimes|h\rangle\otimes|h\rangle=\sum_{b\in\{0,1\}^3}\alpha^{3-|b|}\beta^{|b|}|b\rangle\tag1
\end{equation}
where $|b|$ denotes the Hamming weight of the bitstring $b$. The action of $\text{CSWAP}$ on the computational basis is a permutation that preserves the Hamming weight. Therefore, $|hhh\rangle$ is also a $+1$ eigenstate of $\text{CSWAP}$. Consequently, $|hhh\rangle$ is a $+1$ eigenstate of every product in $\langle\text{CSWAP},H\rangle$. Moreover, by continuity of matrix-vector product, $|hhh\rangle$ is a $+1$ eigenstate of every unitary in $\overline{\langle\text{CSWAP},H\rangle}$. But
\begin{align}
\text{CCZ}|hhh\rangle=\text{CCZ}(&\alpha^3|000\rangle+\alpha^2\beta|001\rangle+\ldots+\alpha\beta^2|110\rangle+\beta^3|111\rangle)=\tag2\\
=\,&\alpha^3|000\rangle+\alpha^2\beta|001\rangle+\ldots+\alpha\beta^2|110\rangle-\beta^3|111\rangle\tag3
\end{align}
so $|hhh\rangle$ is not a $+1$ eigenstate of $\text{CCZ}$ and therefore $\text{CCZ}\notin\overline{\langle \text{CSWAP},H\rangle}$.

N.B. it should be possible to use the states appearing in equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ to compute a lower bound on the distance (in some chosen metric) between $\text{CCZ}$ and $\langle \text{CSWAP},H\rangle$.

You can exactly implement a Toffoli using CSWAPs catalyzed by a singlet state:

The singlet state is the -1 eigenstate of the swap gate, and you can get phase kickback from a swap by using cswap, so you can create the catalyst by postselection:

There's probably some simpler way to do this, but this proves it's possible to do exactly.

I'm interested in only the 3-qubit case without the use of ancillas or encoded (approximate) universality.

Oh. Well that's harder. You're sure you don't want to just be able to do the gate exactly with 7 CSWAPs, instead of doing it approximately with presumably hundreds or thousands of CSWAPs?

Thanks for the very thought out and thorough answer. From a practical standpoint I completely agree, but I'm trying to prove/disprove the universality of CSWAP + H and the proof/disproof of this question seems key. If it helps Pauli X can be included in the gateset.

Actually, your construction might be all that's needed. It implements an exact unencoded toffoli, correct?

@Jonas The construction basically uses the ancilla construction to implement a Pauli Z (which, given you have H, is equivalent to X).

@NorbertSchuch You're right. Thanks.

@craig-gidney I think your answer is all that's needed to prove universality of CSWAP + H which I see asked about here on occasion. I'll post another question soon where you can basically cut-and-paste your answer from here.
